# How to create a Lamda@Edge from the command line?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

Is there a way to create a Lambda@Edge from the command line? Or is there a way to take an existing lambda and deploy it to cloudfront from the command line?

I've looked here: `aws lambda ?`
and here: `aws cloudfront ?`

The only thing that looks remotely useful is `update-distribution`.

Comment: I have this problem too! Did you manage to get a good shell script going for it?

Comment: @Snickers3192 Nope : (

Comment: Haha I am pretty close to needing to write one of these, the problem is these cloudfront distributions are so deeply nested with so much configuration, and I only want to change this one part, absolute nightmare. I wish cloudfront behaved the sameway as API GW with using the latest lambda function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've already found it- although I'll grant you that it's pretty arduous.

`aws cloudfront update-distribution` includes the array key `LambdaFunctionAssociations`, which allows you to link existing lambdas (by `LambdaFunctionARN`) to various cache responses.

More information here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudfront/update-distribution.html

Unfortunately, as seems to be the case with all of cloudfront, there's no helper commands to just add/remove lambdas.

If you're scripting you might want to look at `get-distribution` which allows you to at least pre-populate most of the distribution configuration from whatever you've set up in the console; rather than learning everything from scratch.

This document might also be helpful for you: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-overview-required-fields.html as it discusses what information you have to provide to the distribution operation commands.

Comment: Thanks, man. I found some of that info. It's good to have this confirmed. I'll check out those links.

Comment: No worries- Just a shame I can't give you a more convenient way!

Comment: I'm trying to stick with just npm scripts and aws command line for deploying updates. It's almost possible. Would make my life so simple : )